# How to get Active Directory object SID using LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have the command that returns all groups from active directory:

```
  conn.search(f'cn=users,DC=dc,DC=testdomain,DC=link', '(objectclass=group)',paged_size = 1000)
```

In the entery DN I see the group names.
The question is how I can get the SID of each group, so that I have both the Name and the SID of the object.

Answer (score 0):

This now returns the `objectsid`

```
conn.search(f'cn=users,DC=dc,DC=testdomain,DC=link',
'(objectclass=group)',
attributes=['objectsid', 'sAMAccountName'],paged_size = 1000)
```